# Python 3: Change default values of existing function's parameters?

Tags: python, parameters, python-3.x, arguments, default

I'm creating a program which will eventually have like 500 calls for `print` function, and some others too. Each of these functions will take the exact same parameters every time, like this:

```
print(a, end='-', sep='.')
print(b, end='-', sep='.')
print(c, end='-', sep='.')
print(..., end='-', sep='.')
```

Is there a way to change the default values of `print` function's parameters? So that I wouldn't have to type `end='-', sep='.'` every time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can define a special version of `print()` using [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to give it default arguments:

```
from functools import partial

myprint = partial(print, end='-', sep='.')
```

and `myprint()` will then use those defaults throughout your code:

```
myprint(a)
myprint(b)
myprint(c)
```

Comment: This is better than what I was going to attempt.  I was going to do something horrible with `__defaults__` (which apparently doesn't exist on builtin functions anyway ...)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. However, how is this different from defining a new function, like `def myprint(*args): print(*args, end='-', sep'.')` or using `lambda` like Lee suggested? Just curious, is this better in some way?

Comment: @PatrikLippojoki: `functools.partial` codifies defining your own wrapper function into one line. It's better in that it is shorter and clearer (in my view); it signals you are still just calling `print()` but with default arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a lambda function:

```
my_print = lambda x: print(x, end='-', sep='-')
my_print(a)
my_print(b)
my_print(c)
```

Comment: functools.partial is good, just be aware that it only "became" available in Python 2.5+

Comment: Python 2.5 is rather old by now.

Comment: Indeed it is. I know of several vendors that haven't certified their product on anything past RHEL5.4 which still has 2.4 (!!) on it.

Comment: @Lee: Yes. But you can install newer versions side by side. No excuse. But I very well understand what you mean :) Microsoft would tell you in similar case *the older system is not supported*. Yes, it may be arrogant sometimes, but it is also pragmatic.

Comment: With this lambda, `my_print` can only accept one argument, which makes the function far less interesting. And of course, it defeats the purpose of the `sep='-'` .

Answer (score 2):

There is also a method that allows multiple parameters and works with lambdas:

```
my_print = lambda *args: print(*args, end="-", sep=".")
```